# Bootstrap-SASS: uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, sprockets, gemfile

No matter what I do, I always get the error

```
/home/xyz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)
```

when restarting the rails server after installing the bundle. I've tried to change version numbers, delete the .lock file and so on, but nothing is working. I'm using `Rails 4.2.6`.
Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.3.1"

gem 'rails_12factor'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sprockets-rails'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'clockpicker-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.37'

gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootflat-rails' # flat UI skin for bootstrap
```

application.css.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootflat';
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'bootstrap/clockpicker';
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require icheck.min
//= require bootstrap/clockpicker
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I've read many similar questions but none of the answers helped me or caused even more problems. It really should'nt be that hard but I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
bundle update sprockets-rails
```

Comment: Doesn't help sadly, I'm still getting the same error